# orm.CompilationManager Issue: java compilation Error in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I have install hadoop 2.6.0 ,HBase 0.98.12.1-hadoop2 and Sqoop 1.4.6. When i run this using simple Java program its working fine but when i run through spring program it gives error

**Code: java file**

```
String[] cmd = {
            "import",
            "-Dsqoop.hbase.add.row.key=true",
            "--connect",
            "jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/dbname",
            "--username",
            "username",
            "--password",
            "passowrd",
            "--table",
            "Mysql table name",
            "--hbase-table",
            "Hbase table name",
            "--column-family",
            "family name",
            "--columns",
            "Columns names",
            "--hbase-row-key",
            "Key values for Hbase",             
            "--hbase-create-table", "-m", "1" };

    Sqoop.runTool(cmd,config);
```

**Same Code use in SqoopController:**

Log File for when running through Spring:

```
    Sqoop Processing
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,370 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1049)) - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
       2015-07-23 09:32:23,420 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] tool.SqoopTool (SqoopTool.java:loadPluginsFromConfDir(177)) - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,457 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] sqoop.Sqoop (Sqoop.java:<init>(92)) - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,469 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:applyCredentialsOptions(1021)) - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,479 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] sqoop.ConnFactory (ConnFactory.java:loadManagersFromConfDir(273)) - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,648 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] manager.MySQLManager (MySQLManager.java:initOptionDefaults(69)) - Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,649 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] tool.CodeGenTool (CodeGenTool.java:generateORM(92)) - Beginning code generation
        2015-07-23 09:32:23,959 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] manager.SqlManager (SqlManager.java:execute(757)) - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `MODELING3` AS t LIMIT 1
        2015-07-23 09:32:24,004 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] manager.SqlManager (SqlManager.java:execute(757)) - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `MODELING3` AS t LIMIT 1
        2015-07-23 09:32:24,010 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-8] orm.CompilationManager (CompilationManager.java:findHadoopJars(85)) - $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is not set
        /tmp/sqoop-sunplus/compile/84aa64d558f0617e0c6a33d5475d8b9d/MODELING3.java:7: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
/tmp/sqoop-sunplus/compile/84aa64d558f0617e0c6a33d5475d8b9d/MODELING3.java:37: error: cannot access Writable
public class MODELING3 extends SqoopRecord  implements DBWritable, Writable {
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be warned that Sqoop 1 doesn't have any publicly supported APIs. There might and will be a lot of troubles that you will see if you choose to call Sqoop.runTool on your own. Sqoop 2 rectifies that and add support for [public API](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.6/ClientAPI.html).

It seems to me that you might not have all the required dependencies on the classpath when executed via Spring. Have you compared Sqoop's classpath when running standalone and from Spring?